# How do I Rewrite the URL for both a specific url condition and a general url condition, using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a website with a custom (basic) CMS system using PHP. The CMS system lives under admin.php and the rest of the site lives under index.php.

**// Project explanation for more context on the problem (skip to next comment for the actual problem) //**

Both index.php and admin.php takes in GET variables to control the contents of the page. admin.php takes in 3 different GET variables (a, b and c) which defines different funcitonalities.

"A" is for main functionality like "pages - contents of the different pages", "News - Basic blog system" etc.

"B" is sub links specifically for the "pages" functionality to define which page the admin user is modifying.

"C" is also specific for the "pages" functionality and defines the sub-page that the admin user is modifying.

Then the index.php which is the "client-side" of the project takes in two get variables (A and B)

"A" being the page the user is visiting, defined in the database.

"B" being the sub-page the user is visiting, -//-.

**// End of project explenation //**

So I have been trying to use Rewrite in htaccess to rewrite the URL to a more user-friendly string.

*(admin.php)*
Example: admin.php?a=pages&b=home => /admin/pages/home

*(index.php)*
Example: index.php?a=about&b=team => /about/team

And so far the admin Rewrite conditions work perfectly. But I want to implement the client Rewrite conditions, and they collide.

Current .htaccess state:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin/? admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?/([A-Za-z0-9-&]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [NC,L]
```

I have been looking around on the htaccess documentation and on several questions on stack but havn't been able to find a solid solution.

How can I rewrite the url based on if the user is visiting the admin page or the main (index) page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# rewrite admin/
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ admin.php [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ admin.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

# rewrite others
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The weird things is that this empties the $_GET array on the admin part, but not on index...

Comment: I just add the [QSA] flag for that.

Comment: Yes, I updated the .htaccess file and even restarted Apache but it still empties the $_GET array...

Comment: It also doesn't react when I add more than three GET variables underneath /admin, but it does on the regular (index) part...

Comment: You can add more `admin` rules for more than 3. I don't know what is the problem for your empty $_GET array...

Comment: Nothing else in your .htaccess ?

Comment: The problem is that $_GET variables is what drives the admin interface, hence the use of $_GET variables. If the first $_GET variable "a" is set to "pages" it loades a PHP template containing the structure and functionality of the core part of the CMS, which is editing content on a page.

/admin/a/b/c is the lowest you're supposed to be able to get...

Comment: No the .htaccess file only contains the solution you kindly provided.

Comment: I don't need more $_GET variables. The problem is that the /admin doesn't work properly. 

In the admin.php document i wrote: print_r($_GET);

Result: Array ( )

Which means the $_GET array gets emptied.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91209/discussion-between-max-sandelin-and-croises).

Comment: Actually it was, I'll post my solution.

Comment: No, in fact that was not that, i just add the first `$`. I had not seen was missing. You can use mine. With your new login also...